# Find variance $V(W)$ where $W=5 - .5Y$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Can anyone explain how to do problems of this sort? I understand that $V(Y) = E(Y^2) - [E(Y)]^2 $ and I can solve problems asking for the variance / mean but I don't understand how to approach these types of problems.

How do I find $V(W)$ when W is in terms of $Y$?

This is 4.27 from Wackerly's Statics (7th Ed.) The problem statement is:

For certain ore samples, the proportion $Y$ of impurities per sample is a random variable with density function given in Exercise 4.21. The dollar value of each sample is $W =5−.5Y$.

Find the mean and variance of $W$.

The density function of $Y$ is  $f(y) = (3/2)y^2 $ for $ 0 \le y \le 1 $ and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall the property
$$
V(aY+b)=a^2V(Y),
$$ then here one just has to evaluate
$$
V(Y)=\int_0^1 y^2\cdot f(y)\:dy-\left(\int_0^1y\cdot f(y)\:dy \right)^2.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: That makes sense now, I was wondering how the answer was $.25 V(Y)$. Thanks!

Comment: @fluffy_muffin You are welcome.